# How to handle peer dependencies of a JS library with a single export index file in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jestjs, typescript-module-resolution

Apology for the winding question title which might not make sense at first sight. Let me explain.

I have a library package named `foo-bar-ui` for some shared UI components. All the components are exported from a single index file.

```
// index.js
export * from './lib/ComponentA';
export * from './lib/ComponentB';
export * from './lib/ComponentC';
```

And in the application package, I can happily import things from this library in below format.

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from 'foo-bar-ui';
```

And one day I added a new third party dependency `react-xyz` for `ComponentC`. It's only used by `ComponentC`, hence I declared it as a peer dependency in the library package. Any client application consuming this library can install `react-xyz` on its own if it needs to use `ComponentC`.

However, my current application only consumes `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`. Webpack bundling has no complaint at all as it does tree-shaking, which discards `ComponentC` completely hence there is no warning about missing `react-xyz`. But Jest complains on that. Below execution failure is observed in **client applications** consuming the library package, who did not install `react-xyz` as they do not use `ComponentC`.

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react-xyz' from 'node_modules/foo-bar-ui/lib/ComponentC.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/foo-bar-ui/lib/ComponentC.js
      node_modules/foo-bar-ui/index.js'
```

The immediate solution seems to be exporting each individual components separately, like what `lodash-es` does, e.g. `import isNil from 'lodash-es/isNil';`. And [Node.js subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) seems to be the tool doing the job. But I found it problematic with TypeScript, ESLint and Jest all together with module resolution issues.

What's the ultimate recommended approach to solve this problem? It seems straightforward but oddly I could not land on any easy and succinct solution right away.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you cover both of the scenarios, when the library is installed and when it's not. And jest.mock supports ["virtual" modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), allowing you to mock non-existent modules, so your test can look like this:

```
describe('ComponentC', () => {
  describe('with react-xyz', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.mock('react-xyz', () => {
        // return some implementation
      }, { virtual: true });
    })
  });

  describe('without react-xyz', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.mock('react-xyz', () => {
        // throw new Error('Cannot find module')
      }, { virtual: true });
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question. And just corrected it. The Jest execution failure is observed in client applications consuming the library package, who do not need to install `react-xyz` as they do not use `ComponentC`. Asking all such client applications to mock `react-xyz` is not feasible either as it's not much different from asking them to install it as a dev dependency. The idea is to make `ComponentC` "invisible" for clients who do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

For the current being, a temporary solution I opted in is to stop using the single index and directly take the exports from the individual components.

So in a client application, instead of

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from 'foo-bar-ui';
```

I would have

```
import { ComponentA } from 'foo-bar-ui/dist/features/componentA';
import { ComponentB } from 'foo-bar-ui/dist/features/componentB';
```

This works but it's just that the import statements are not as neat as before.

We could try to eliminate the `/dist/features` portion. [Subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) could be of help, but I found it to be not working well with TypeScript, ESLint and Jest etc.

- https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1868
- https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/12270